# wordpress blog menu link not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, blogs

I am unable to open my blog menu item. I have a category called "Blog" and that is a top level menu item.

The site is http://qhr.com.au

I am able to use all other menu items (until I am on the blog page). The blog menu only opens on right click - "Open in new window".

Once I am on the category page, the link "read more" (and post title) won't take me to the actual blog post. Although, once again, I can right click and open as. The URL is correct in the browser but it won't work with left click.

Also, once I do get to the blog page, I am unable to navigate back to the homepage.

I had it working before and all menu links, blog post and category links were fine. I have deactivated all plugins and reversed any changes made (added - then removed -social media share/follow links).

Comment: Did you Change anything in the Source Code?

Comment: I didn't build this site and I'm trying to work out how to fix these issues. I'm not sure what was changed in the source code by the initial web designer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some issues with your menu. Once i scroll down to the footer, the menu doesn't work smoothly.

1. the default logo of the theme is still loading. I guess, that your theme has logo upload option under theme option/ settings.
2. the 'Home' link is wrong. if you have *#home* under Home menu link replace that with a '/'

else

if you have bought the theme I would suggest you to contact the developer/ seller.

Or

can you please check what is wrong on this section?

```
<div class="body_classes">home,page,page-id-5,page-template,page-template-full_width,page-template-full_width-php,ajax_fade,page_not_loaded,smooth_scroll,,wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-3.6.12,vc_responsive</div>
                </div>
                        <div cl                     
                    <div class="q_slider">
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. I didn't build the site, I'm trying to help them work out what is going on. The menu is a major issue but the contact form is also not working. I'll have a look at that section you added.